# EventListener returning a value

Tags: java, swing, event-handling, return-value

1. First there is a class example with 3 string variables.

   class Example
    {

   String name1;

   String name2;

   String name3;

   }

2 we create an object in main class

```
  Example[] obj=new Example[10];
   for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
 {
 obj[i]=new Example();
 }

 for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{

   ???obj[i]=some_magicfunction_of_listenForButtonclass //the listenforbutton returns an      
}                                                                                   obj
```

3.next we create a a panel in frame containing  3 textfield(,jcomp1jcomp2,jcomp3),then we create a button(jcomp4) that is used to store the values

3.we define actionListener for the button jcomp4

```
ListenForButton lbutton=new ListenForButton();
jcomp4.addActionListener(lbutton);
```

4.now here is the question, can you think how to define a  ListenForButton such that the actionperformed monitors for button click and returns an object(comprising of the 3 values form the textfield) when the button is clicked

Thanks,

Comment: Returns to where? Sounds more like you want to implement some kind observer pattern. Remember, events may occur at any time, and it's (I believe in this case) the EDT that is telling you about the event...

Comment: @MadProgrammer i need to return to the obj[i]. Basically for each time my button being clicked my obj[] is going to store the triplets. Could  you suggest some simple technique or concept, thanks

Comment: Use an observer pattern. Create a custom ActionListener which takes some kind of interface which has a method that you can pass the result to. Pass this interface to your action listener.

Comment: @MadProgrammer,thanks!!!